How to configure max request body size in Elysia JS | Bun JS
I am trying to implement a simple file upload feature in Elysia JS. When uploading a larger file (1.6GB) I get the following message "413 Request Entity Too Large". I have worked with Frameworks such as Express and Fastify in NodeJS and there we have a defined way of configuring it. However, I have searched on Elysia docs and there is no such method defined there. What should be the solution to it?

This is a question you would get a better answer by asking on their Discord channel.

It was solved from this issue: https://github.com/elysiajs/elysia/issues/266
